# XMLTABLE ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column

Tags: oracle, xmltable

I have a table with xmltype field. In this field there is a xml file.
When i do a select from this field like:

```
    SELECT  
        x.resources as item_name
    FROM LOAD_XML t,          
    XMLTABLE (  
    '/Document/Chapters/Chapter/Position'  
    PASSING  xml_data  
    COLUMNS 
        resources varchar2(4000) PATH '@Caption'
    ) x
    where
        XML_FILE_NAME = 'test.xml'
```

I found error strings of xml the Caption is realy long, but not so much:

```
  <Position Caption="Газовая приточная установка в составе: модуль нагрева рекуперативный, 880 кВт - АТРИ МНР 880 (1 шт.), горелка газовая предварительного смешивания - АТРИ PREMIX 880 модулируемая (1 шт.), блок воздушного фильтра на горелку - АТРИ Premix ФП (1 шт.), модуль фильтров панельных - АТРИ ФП (1 шт.), счетчик газа турбинный - СТГ-50-100-2 (1 шт.), клапан воздухоприемный ОТКРЫТО-ЗАКРЫТО -  ГЕРМИК-С-1500(Н)-2400 (1шт.), вентустановка - АТРИ ВБ 100.22/970(1064) (1шт.), частотный преобразователь Schneider - ATV212HD22N4 22,0 кВт (1шт.), шумоглушитель - пластины 5х200 мм (1шт.), датчик температуры - ТС035Л-50М (1шт.), датчик температуры - КДТ 50 (1шт.), датчик-реле давления воздуха - LGW 3 A2 0,4...3 mbar (1шт.), датчик-реле давления газа ГАЗ МАХ - GW 150 A6 10...150mbar (1шт.), модуль управления и защиты нагревателя + система автоматического поддержания расхода воздуха - ШКА-01-МУЗН.С7+САУ-ПР (1шт.), стационарный измеритель скорости потока воздуха - (1шт.), измеритель дифференциального давления + монтжный комплект - АДР-05.5 (1шт.), модуль обслуживания для уличного исполнения - АТРИ МОУ-880.Г (1шт.), вводное распределительное устройство - Шкаф ВРУ (1шт.), модуль сигнализации и управления главным клапаном - МСУ-ГлКл (1шт.), термостат - FI-TO2A (1шт.), дымоходы утепленные - АТРИ ДХУ (1 компл.)" Number="451" Code="ООО  Инжгазпром " Units="шт." SysID="297" Quantity="1" PriceLevel="2001" PzSync="Yes" Vr2001="10087">
```

I have an error:
ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column
01401. 00000 -  "inserted value too large for column"
*Cause:    The value inserted was too large for the given column.
*Action:   Do not insert a value greater than what the column can hold.

But the max length of selected fied is max(length(x.resources)) = 1297

Please help!

Comment: Could you provide a sample of that XML, or at least the `resources` element or `@Caption` attribute that you are trying to select? Also, try changing `varchar2(4000)` to `clob` and see what that gets you.

Comment: @gmiley I found string which show an error. See a  fragment of xml code in my first post

Comment: Question, if you are only accessing values from the XML, why not use `ExtractValue` instead of joining an `XmlTable`? I can put the query below in an answer if you would like.

Comment: 1297 _characters_ might well exceed the maximum length of 4000 _bytes_ of a `VARCHAR2` column depending on the character set and characters in the string

Comment: I use Oracle XE 11g with default preferences

Comment: Did you try changing it to a `clob` type instead of the `varchar2` to see if you get results?